# Restore previous In-app purchase after unistalling and installing the app

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

i am developing an android application which has in-app purchase.i am able to complete in-app purchase succesfully,but not able to restore the purchases after uninstalling and installing the app again.
I am using In-app Billing Version 2 API.
I am using RestoreTransactions method and getting error RESULT_DEVELOPER_ERROR.
i used signed  apk and also added the permissions in the manifest file.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Your gonna have to give us a little more information than that. Otherwise we can just guess what's wrong. Show us some code. Show us interesting parts of the logcat output. Show what you have tried so far to solve the problem and tell us what you think the reason for the problem is.

Comment: why are you using v2 when there is a v3?

Comment: @tyczj can you please provide a sample code for version 3? please help.

Comment: look at the developer website for examples, its there for a reason